# Как ограничить доступ к сайт по различным сетевым картам?

Tags: apache, сеть

У меня стоит сервер с сайтом и апачем, в нём 4 сетевых карточки, мне необходимо ограничить доступность сайта на одну из сетевых карточке. То есть чтобы по трём он был доступный, а по четвертой нет.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется самый простой способ - это закрыть фаерволом порт(ы). Можно, конечно, поиздеваться и над апачем, но стоит ли оно того? В любом случае при смене ip-адреса на сетевой карте надо будет менять настройки, но в случае с фаерволом не придется передергивать апач.

Comment: А придется переписывать правила фаервола.

Comment: Listen IF_IP_ADDR:PORT - писать три разрешающих правила вместо одного запрещающего? Каждый раз лезть в конфиг после изменения любого из трех адресов? Оно вам действительно надо?

Comment: 1. А вдруг у человека политика по умолчанию для фаервола на блокировку? Которую я бы рекомендовал использовать на сервере.2. Во-первых вы предлагаете заставить слушать лишние интерфейсы, не много нагрузки, но зачем? А во-вторых  еще нагрузить сервер фильтрацией. Умное решение!Никогда не понимал людей, которые вместо одного решения, причем стандартного, выбирают два, усложняя понимание системы.

Comment: Фаервол по умолчанию слушает ВСЕ интерфейсы, иначе он и не нужен. Если фаервол изначально настроен на блокировку, то проблема вообще не стоит - просто разрешаем все, что нам нужно, в т.ч. и прохождение трафика на апач через указанные интерфейсы. Ваш вариант жизнеспособен, с этим я не спорю. Но задача стоит сетевая. Вот пришел новый админ, который видит что сайт не открывается из какой-то подсети или стало необходимо заблокировать не всю сеть, а часть. Куда в первую очередь будет смотреть админ? На антивирус и фаервол. Это и есть одно стандартное решение, не надо усложнять жизнь себе и другим.

Comment: А я говорил, что-то про фаервол? Вы мне заявляете, что сложно три правила в апаче, а одно не сложно, я вам отвечаю, что если фаервол на блокировке, то те же три правила вам придется мучить.Хм, одно решение вместо двух, вот это я усложняю жизнь. Речь не идет о блокировке для части сети, иначе было бы больше смысла в вашем решении.И да, логично, что первым делом админ посмотрит на фаервол, чтобы офигеть от находчивости предыдущих умельцев.А еще вы не сможете на четвертую сеть на порт 80 ничего другого повесить, если понадобится.

Comment: По-моему вы уже сами запутались. Поверьте опыту - простое и очевидное решение оказывается часто лучшим. Сейчас о чем-то речь не идет, а завтра условия поменяются. Поэтому нужно оставлять место для маневра. Странно вообще читать такие комментарии от специалиста по сетевой безопасности.

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем я запутался. И не понимаю, почему вы считаете свое решение более очевидным. С тех пор как в конфигурации доступны множественные директивы `Listen` это наиболее прямое решение, которые не требует дополнительной настройки.Как раз таки в области сетевой безопасности, я предпочитаю закрыть все, что не должно быть открытым и закрыть это правильно. А так же не открывать то, чего не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Используя директиву конфигурации, обычно `httpd.conf`

```
Listen IF_IP_ADDR:PORT
```

можно добиться привязки к конкретному IP.

После вам следует перезапустить сервер.